# How many toss a coin attempts required so the noise is always less than 1%?

Tags: probability, distributions, experiment-design, random-generation

I don't know what is it in statistic term, but I will say it the noise.

Noise is defined as absolute difference between real percentage result after experiment and ideal probability.

The question is **minimum number of attempts** required to toss a coin so that the absolute difference between the percentage of occurrence of one side of the coin and 50% is guaranteed to be less than 1%?  And how do you guarantee it?

So for example after 100 trials, one side tail percentage number is 49.4%, when reduced absolutely by 50% the result is 0.6% which is less than 1%. We can say the noise is 0.6%.

When repeated 100 times again after new experiment, the result is still less than 1%.

How do you guarantee all 100 tries it's always less than 1%?

**Edit:**

So it's impossible the noise is **always** less than 1% after discussion in chat.

Okay I change the question, how many toss coin that should I do so the noise is being less than 1% with probability being success is 99%?

Comment: What do you mean by “guarantee”? If you mean that we would be assured of being within $1\%$, the task is impossible. All we can do is get a small but positive probability.

Comment: @Dave I think you could write a complete answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141181/discussion-on-question-by-muhammad-ikhwan-perwira-how-many-toss-a-coin-attempts).

Comment: The Normal approximation says you need 16,587 trials.  An exact Binomial calculation shows you can get away with just 16,500 trials, but no fewer.  With 16,502 trials, there is a 99.006% chance of observing between 8085 and 8415 tails.

Comment: @whuber I have proved it with python and I think your answer is true. Can you give me detail where all those numbers calculated?

Comment: I used an exhaustive search beginning at the solution indicated by the Normal approximation (which is 16,587 trials).